# Discord.py I have problem with getting a list of banned users

Tags: discord.py

```
for member in ctx.guild.users:
    print(str(member.name))
    print(str(await is_banned(ctx.guild, member))+"\n\n")

async def is_banned(guild, user):
    try:
        entry = await guild.fetch_ban(user)
    except discord.NotFound:
        return False
    return True
```

This is the code I'm using, but I get only the users that are not banned. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it doesnt show people who are banned. Is that `ctx.guild.members` only shows persons who are in the server. Thus excluding those who are banned. As those people arent in the server anymore.

This results in a list with people who arent banned.

If you want to get a list of banned people you need to do `await ctx.guild.bans()`. As explained in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20ban#discord.Guild.bans). This will return a list of banned users.

Comment: Oh huh, I helped them out (the ``is_banned`` function is written by me) because they wanted to see if a user is banned or not and now it turns out that they just wanted to know a list of banned users, so ``bans()`` is good enough. That's why you always read the documentation before trying to do something that might have already been done for you!

Comment: Thank you Deru and Lu M, I'm new to discord.py, so it's hard for me to understand the API Reference.